# How to store files to local Git repository in PHP

Tags: php, git, file-storage

I'd like to know how to store files to my local Git repository through PHP. In my Moodle plugin I have functionality where the user can store their files to the local default Moodledata folder. I'd like to know though how to store the data to my local Git repository instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `shell_exec`, which lets you run command line instructions directly from PHP. However, since you'll presumably be taking user input (filenames), that's *extremely* dangerous. I'd look into shell argument escaping before doing this.

Another way is to use a library like [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/), which does all that protection for you, but you'd have to build a wrapper around it to allow you to use it from PHP.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. So by using `shell_exec` I'd be able to run commands to be able to store and retrieve files in my Git repository just like I do in Git Bash? Do you know of a good website that explains roughly how to do this?

Comment: You're doing this from Windows? You'll likely not be able to directly invoke git bash commands from shell_exec, because shell_exec will call the normal windows command line. However, I believe git can be configured at installation time to be callable from cmd, so you may find that useful.

Comment: Once you do that, it's quite simple: shell_exec("git status") will run the git status command.

Comment: ahh I think you're right about that config at installation. I'll run the installation again and I'll let you know. I'm new to Git so I'm just beginning to learn about it all..can I ask you what sort of command would I do to store a file to the repository? For some reason I can't find much about it on the web. Maybe I'm googling the wrong thing?

Comment: Ah - in that case, try a basic git tutorial. You're looking for the `add` and `commit` commands.

Comment: Hi again Ian, I ran the installation again and you were right about the setting to allow Git to be called from cmd. I'm a bit confused now though.. I've got my PHP script where the user selects a file from the file picker for the file be subsequently saved.. what would the bash command look like for a file to be saved to the repository? And how would I specify in the PHP script where to look for the repository? Sorry for my possibly 'simple' questions

Comment: actually think I've understood it now.. so I send the file the user wants to store over to the git repository using standard PHP file storage commands then execute the `git add`, `commit` etc commands using `shell_exec`?